# Angular js Вывод елемента соотвественно, есть ли елемент в масиве

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="x in records" ng-init="x.sys=false">
    <div ng-if="(x==2)" ng-model="x.sys">{{x}}</div>
    <div ng-show="!x.sys">q</div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.records = [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
      ]
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Выводит: 
q
2
q
q
q

Нужно:

q
2
q
q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки в консоли ясно дают понять, что не так:

> TypeError: Cannot create property 'sys' on number '4'

данная ошибка возникает при попытке ангуляром выполнить

```
x.sys=false
```

А именно примитиву добавить свойство.

Далее: нет смысла использовать директиву `ng-model` на элементе `div` - она просто ничего не делает.

И, наконец, почему выводится лишняя `q`: так как добавление свойства завершилось неудачей, выражение `x.sys` всегда возвращает undefined, что в совокупности с `!` возвращает значение *true* для директивы `ng-show`.

Таким образом, когда элемент массива равен 2, выводится элемент с `ng-if` и элемент с `ng-show`, который выводится всегда.

Для решения можно воспользоваться соседним ответом, либо использовать переменную локального для `ng-repeat` скопа, например так:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="x in records" ng-init="sys=x==2">
    <div ng-if="(x==2)">{{x}}</div>
    <div ng-show="!sys">q</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
<div ng-repeat="x in records">
  <div ng-if="x==2">{{x}}</div>
  <div ng-if="x!=2">q</div>
</div>
```